# Как сгенерировать .wav файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, wav

Допустим, мне нужно создать .wav файл, имеющий несколько значений частоты (в Гц) и длительности (в миллисекундах). Как мне его создать, имея массив значений, допустим

```
[1000,3000,5000,7000,8000]
```

или

```
[100,200]
```

, и массив длительности, допустим

```
[1000,1000,2000,3000,1000]
```

или

```
[1000,1]
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Я когда-то писал скрипт для подобной задачи.

Если что-то будет не понятно, то вот ссылка на подробное описание wav-формата http://microsin.net/programming/pc/wav-format.html

Примечание: этот скрипт работает с входными данными в виде списка целых чисел от 0 до 255, где каждое значение - значение звукового сигнала, и таких значений 44100 за секунду. Соответственно, вам нужно будет сгенерировать список этих значений из ваших частот и длительностей. Я привёл пример генерации данных для прямоугольной волны длительностью 1 секунда и частотой 220 герц.

```
from typing import List


CHUNK_ID = 'RIFF'
FORMAT = 'WAVE'
SUB_CHUNK_1_ID = 'fmt '
SUB_CHUNK_1_SIZE = 16
AUDIO_FORMAT = 1
NUM_CHANNELS = 1
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100
BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 8
BLOCK_ALIGN = int((BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8) * NUM_CHANNELS)
AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND = SAMPLE_RATE * BLOCK_ALIGN
SUB_CHUNK_2_ID = 'data'


def bytes_with_align(value, num_bytes):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value.to_bytes(num_bytes, byteorder='little')
    assert num_bytes >= len(value)
    bytes_value = bytes(value, encoding='ASCII')
    rest = b'\x00' * (num_bytes - len(bytes_value))
    return rest + bytes_value


def make_file_data(data: List[int]):

    sub_chunk_2_size = len(data)
    chunk_size = 36 + sub_chunk_2_size  # file size minus chunk_id and format parts

    # header_parts: (value, byte_size)
    header = (
        (CHUNK_ID, 4),
        (chunk_size, 4),
        (FORMAT, 4),
        (SUB_CHUNK_1_ID, 4),
        (SUB_CHUNK_1_SIZE, 4),
        (AUDIO_FORMAT, 2),
        (NUM_CHANNELS, 2),
        (SAMPLE_RATE, 4),
        (AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, 4),
        (BLOCK_ALIGN, 2),
        (BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 2),
        (SUB_CHUNK_2_ID, 4),
        (sub_chunk_2_size, 4),
    )
    header_bytes = b''.join(bytes_with_align(*part) for part in header)

    file_data = header_bytes + b''.join(sample.to_bytes(int(BITS_PER_SAMPLE/8), byteorder='little') for sample in data)

    return file_data


# Работать с этим так:

duration = 1  # Файл длиной 1 секунда
freq = 220  # Звук частотой 220 герц
period = 44100 / freq
seq_size = duration * 44100

data = [0 if (x % period < period/2) else 255 for x in range(seq_size)]


with open('test.wav', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(make_file_data(data))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Только не понятно, почему вы в  `data = [0 if (x % freq < freq/2) else 255 for x in range(seq_size)]` используете именно либо 0, либо 255.

Comment: @TheNick-Ник для беззнакового однобайтового целового числа 255 - это максимальное значение. Т.к. для простоты я взял прямоугольный сигнал, то используется только максимальное и минимальное из возможных значений.

Comment: У меня там, кстати, ошибка, при вычислении data нужно брать конечно же не частоту, а период. Поправил.